Is there any disadvantage in including more header files than you need?
I'm in the process of reworking the headers of a larger project. The headers haven't seen any care in a long time, so what we have is a long list of headers pointing directly at .h files located in the file system like so:
#include "src/lib/math/Vec.h"
#include "src/lib/math/Vec2.h"
#include "src/lib/math/Vec3.h"

I figured it would be a nice cleaning step rework the headers to look more like
#include <vecs.h>

For this, I need to provide an include directory so that the < > syntax can be resolved, which is not a big deal. But also, I need to prepare a vecs.h header file that includes a lot of other headers, a lot of these Vec* classes in this example. So when I include the <vecs.h> in some place in my code, I actually include a lot of classes that are never even used.
Is this problematic in any way?

TLDR yes, including unecessary it takes up compile time. The rule is in your header file use forward declarations if you can and only include header files for types you use in that header file (minimal complete set). And in source files include only those header files you need for types you use in your implementation (not already included in the header file for that source file)

Thank you for the comments and answers. On a side note, I find it very annoying that basically every question gets closed on SO within a few minutes, and ever so often due to a wrong reason. The referenced duplicate does not answer the same question I had. I did not ask about including the same header file in multiple places, but whether it is bad in some way to include more than what you need.

@Marcell focus on the answers in marked duplicates, not the original questions. If you cannot find anything there which answers your specific question, then [edit] and explain why not.

@Marcell For small projects it probably doesn't matter but when you have code bases with millions of lines of code and thousands of files including too many files adds up and slows down builds. So the answer I can give you is including header files is not free

Thank you for the responses. I was not aware of the looming cost of compile times and I will rethink my approach.

There is a tool called include what you use which can help in making sure you #include header files that the file uses, and not #include header files that the file does not use.

I was not aware of the looming cost of compile times and I will rethink my approach. This doesn't usually cause you an issue with small projects however when your code grows and uses lots of template libraries it can cause you minutes on each build. I have projects that are several hundred thousand lines of code and several hundred source files. I have in the past spent  several weeks work optimizing the build performance because waiting 20+ minutes on most builds was taking too much time and cutting into my productivity.

the #include statement is simply "copy all file content and paste it here", it takes time, and will result in a slower compilation, because the compiler has to parse a larger file.
precompiled headers improve compile times, so if you have a file you need to include everywhere then put it in a precompiled header, otherwise include only the files you need, and nothing more.
